# lua attempt to call global write (a nil value)

Tags: lua

I get lua error attempt to call global write    (a nil value ) if I try to run this program, How to fix this ?

```
page = [[
<html>
<head>
<title>Practing Lua</title>
<body>
<a href = "http://lua.org"> LUA</a>
</body>
</html>]]
write(page)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. If `write(page)` is supposed to output HTML so it appears with links in different color, images visible etc rather than a marked up text, then `write` must be a function that sends the given text to an HTML renderer, such as a web browser. It is likely that code in your book is using the author's library to write to a web browser. If the author's intention is for you to follow the examples in book, the author likely made this library available from the book's website. Dig in the intro of book.

Answer (score 3):

`write` isn't a pre-defined global lua function. you're probably looking for `io.write` instead?

i suggest [reading the lua docs](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html) when you're looking for specific functionality from the built-in libraries.

Comment: io.write(page) gives exactly what I have written along with all the tags.I want it to be replaced with the appropriate out which I would fetch via HTML.

Comment: Yes, `io.write` just dumps whatever you give it to stdout. I don't understand your second sentence - what are you trying to do?

Comment: I am sorry Typo! I meant is there a way to obtain output as I will get using HTML ? I got this code in a book ,there it's just "write" and not io.write so I expected output same as an HTML page would look like ,Is it me misunderstanding it  or is it possible to achieve that ?

Comment: without seeing the book/example, I probably can't help you there. it sounds like the author probably implemented the `write` function in the example elsewhere in the book, perhaps?

Comment: No, I made sure of that.It's really not that way,Fairly beginning of the book it is. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

you may need to include a library file at first ( the command can be found in the documentaries of your software.  ) i.e.

```
dofile(core.app_path() .. "\\strategies\\standard\\include\\helper.lua");
```